# Scenekit : Child node is not getting added properly to parent node

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am adding plane node to the sphere node using hit test. whenever I tried to add plane node to the sphere node. it's shape is different each time. I am not getting why this is happening.

Code :

```
    let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 10)
    sphere.segmentCount = 360
    let material = textureProvider.getTextureMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "sample")
    sphere.firstMaterial = material
    let sphereNode = SCNNode()
    sphereNode.geometry = sphere

    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)


func getTextureMaterial() -> SCNMaterial {
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.mipFilter = .nearest
    material.diffuse.magnificationFilter = .linear
   // material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(-1, 1, 1)
    material.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
    material.cullMode = .front
   // material.isDoubleSided = true
    return material
}



@objc func handleTap(rec: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if rec.state == .ended {
            let location: CGPoint = rec.location(in: sceneView)
            let hits = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: nil)

            if !hits.isEmpty {
                let result: SCNHitTestResult = hits[0]
                 createPlaneNode(result: result)
            }

        }
    }

func createPlaneNode(result : SCNHitTestResult) {
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: 5, height: 5)
        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        plane.firstMaterial?.cullMode = .front
        let planeNode = SCNNode()
        planeNode.name = "B"
        planeNode.geometry = plane
        planeNode.position = result.worldCoordinates
        result.node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    }
```

Please help

Comment: some code example would be very useful

Comment: @AndreyGershengoren added tried code

Comment: When you say that the plane is a different shape each time it is added, what do you mean? Could it be that you are seeing the plane fro a different angle each time and so it looks to be a different shape?

Comment: @theMikeSwan Yes, I guess you are right. I am using one camera to see sphere's content. How to place the child node into parent node with correct orientation/shape/angle?

Comment: If your camera doesn't move and the sphere doesn't move then the plane should show up looking the same each time. If either thing moves/rotates then the plane will be seen from a different angle. The plane will always get added with the same relative orientation to the sphere so you have to either figure out the angle from the base orientation of the plane to the camera and set the Euler angles correctly or take a look at `SCNBillboardConstraint` if you want the plane always pointed at the camera.

Comment: @theMikeSwan Thanks. I used SCNBox and designed front face of it and used SCNBillBoardConstraint to always face it to the camera. It's hack for now. But I will have to dig more into it.